# Specflow in .net version 3.0.225 does not load the feature.cs file in my project

Tags: .net

[image]I have installed the latest stable version 3.0.225 of specflow in my .net project v4.6.1, together with Specflow.Tools.MsBuild.Generation v3.0.225. 
When I add the feature file (SpecFlowFeature1.feature) and build the project it generates the feature.cs (SpecFlowFeature1.feature.cs) file but doesn't add it to my project. It only exists as a file in the same folder as the feature file. 
I have removed the “SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator” from the Custom Tool field
I have added to my project the following by no luck. Am I missing something?

```
<Target Name="AfterUpdateFeatureFilesInProject">
    <!-- include any generated SpecFlow files in the compilation of the project if not included yet -->
    <ItemGroup>
      <Compile Include="Features\*.feature.cs" />
    </ItemGroup>
  </Target>
```

Comment: Can you share the screenshot of your feature file . usually when u expand feature file,.cs file will be shown

Comment: Attached is a screenshot, the feature file does not expand

Answer (score 0):

Had similar problem on .net v4.7.1 and SpecFlow 2.3.2. Fixed it with following steps:

1) In Visual Studio open Tools -> Options -> SpecFlow -> Enable SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator = True

[image]

2) Right click on .feature file -> Properties.

3) Set Custom Tool = SpecFlowSingleFileGenerator

[image]

More info here: https://github.com/techtalk/SpecFlow/wiki/Generate-Tests-from-MsBuild